# Development of Mobile Games

Tags: 2d-games, cocoonjs, construct-2

There are times I have been researching on the best way and tool for developing mobile phone games, and came to a small conclusion: I need help from someone with knowledge to tell me what is the best tool for game development. 
I've tried to be easy to construct 2 but did not get anywhere, I had the whole game ready, but I do not run perfectly on my phone. 
It crashes, closes alone, and the game is in the style flappy birds, however, with better graphics actually, only 10% better, and yet, I still have automatic locks and crashes the game because of that. 
My phone is a samsung galaxy tab.

So what tool do you recommend? I like to think of platform games, in the style mário bross. As such, and as educational side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to make ISO games as it has the largest market right now. Ojective-C has lots of useful APIs and easy to learn and use, but the only problem is in order to test it on your phone and upload to Apple Store, you will need to buy their developer membership which costs like $100 per year.

Comment: Thanks Luo Sen, and for android? Should i build a native code?

Comment: Luo Sen, thanks for your recommendation, iOS is the best than Android for the market of games? Well, so i'll focus on this

Comment: Android is java based and if you know java it is easy, and it is open source which means you can test and upload do whatever you want to, but in terms of markets base. ISO wins.

Comment: just a question: ISO = iOS?

Comment: yes, for iphone and ipad

Comment: One more thing, can i make html5 games and run on my iphone like android web view?
I want to create a app that runs index.html game. Apple left this happens?

Comment: Hello, I believe there is a software called PhoneGap, it creates a web application that runs on all systems such as IOS or android, and it will be run as a application but it is a web